# Invalid policy document or request headers

Tags: fine-uploader

I have been struggling to see some light on Fine Uploader and getting "Invalid policy document or request headers!"

My java script

```
var s3Uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    debug: true,
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-s3'),
    template: 'qq-template-s3',
    request: {
        endpoint: "http://xx_mybucket_xx.s3.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: "xx_my_access_public_key_xx"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php"
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php?success",
        params: {
            isBrowserPreviewCapable: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
        }
    },
```

in my endpoint-cors.php

```
$clientPrivateKey = 'xx_my_access_secret_key_xx';
..
$serverPublicKey = 'xx_my_aws_admin_public_key_xx';
$serverPrivateKey = 'xx_my_aws_admin_private_key_xx';
...
$expectedBucketName = 'xx_mybucket_xx';
$expectedHostName = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com'; 

function handleCorsRequest() {  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost');
}
```

AWS policy for the user with key xx_my_access_public_key_xx/xx_my_access_secret_key_xx

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xx_mybucket_xx/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AWS CORS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-meta-qqfilename</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-date</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Request Header

```
Request URL:http://localhost/app/ci/php-s3-server/endpoint-cors.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:16
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 28 Mar 2016 21:10:38 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:295
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_f20b39b0cd3496e33513d2bacf01cb08=testuser%7C1459195033%7CKXV9QrEMyDcLAYJlaGTgICQ74f8iTwm5yUxGjR0SvO0%7C96cdcd43f9a8bb882ca9603a76e08da613398daa202a5b5a1674b5f28ef899a9; PHPSESSID=5bhdaq99o6pa0cagp6d0rsq9s2; _ga=GA1.1.446199661.1458860695
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/templates/s3test.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
view source
{expiration: "2016-03-28T21:15:38.137Z",…}
conditions
:
[{acl: "private"}, {bucket: "xx_mybucket_xx"}, {Content-Type: "image/png"},…]
expiration
:
"2016-03-28T21:15:38.137Z"
```

Response

```
{"invalid":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from your server indicates that the server is rejecting the signature request. If you are using the [example PHP S3 signature server code provided in the Fine Uploader GitHub repo](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-s3-server), the request will be rejected for one or more of the following reasons:

- Bucket associated with the request does not match the value you have set for the `$expectedBucketName` variable in your PHP file. This could happen if the bucket name you have provided in not correct. Check and be sure the bucket name you have provided is accurate.
- Size of the file is greater than the value you have specified for `$expectedMaxSize`. You should set this to `null` if you don't want to validate size, or a specific number in bytes if you *do* want to restrict files to a certain size.

Also, there doesn't appear to be any reason for you to use endpoint-cors.php. Based on the JS you have posted, all requests to your signature server are same-origin. You should be using endpoint.php.

Comment: I have verified that value specified $expectedBucketName matches with AWS bucket name. I did not set any value for S3_MAX_FILE_SIZE,hence $expectedMaxSize is null by default.

Comment: When changes to endpoint.php......received.......[Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Error attempting to parse signature response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <qq.log  [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Received an empty or invalid response from the server!qq.log @ [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Policy signing failed.  Received an empty or invalid response from the server!

Comment: response....... <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: _method in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\app\ci\php-s3-server\endpoint.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: headers in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\app\ci\php-s3-server\endpoint.php</b> on line <b>114</b><br />
{"invalid":true}

Comment: line#83 in endpoint.php is ...if ($_REQUEST['_method'] != null) {

Comment: line#114 in endpoint.php is ... $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];

Comment: Another item to NOTE; I am using all.fine-uploader.min.js, ui-scripts.js, fine-uploader-new.min.css, fine-uploader-gallery.min.css from http://fineuploader.com/demos.html as files downloaded from DOWNLOAD section did not give me UPLOAD widget/section

Comment: The output you are posting here does not match the output you have posted in your question. It looks like you have recently configured your PHP server to echo warnings/debug statements. You'll need to turn that off. If you are certain that the `$expectedMaxSize` is null, then the `$expectedBucketName` is incorrect. There are no other possible reasons why the response would include an `invalid` property with a value of `true`. It's either the file is larger than `$expectedMaxSize` or the bucket does not match `$expectedBucketName`.

Comment: Above response came when changed to endpoint.php. If I change back to endpointp-cors.php, I am getting same response as previous one;

Comment: I would suggest adding temporary log statements to the end of the `isPolicyValid` method to determine which of the two values are not as you expect.

Comment: my logging is working now!.....in endpoint-cors.php I set $expectedMaxSize = null; below is the $policyStr and it has value 15000000 - where does this number come from? Reason being....parsedMaxSize:15000000 and expectedMaxSize: <empty>.....hence isPolicyValid($policy) becomes FALSE

Comment: {"expiration":"2016-03-30T02:30:24.446Z","conditions":[{"acl":"private"},{"bucket":"xx_mybucket_xx"},{"Content-Type":"image\/png"},{"success_action_status":"200"},{"key":"ea96f566-9424-46e2-b910-fe9f010476c7.png"},{"x-amz-meta-qqfilename":"art_collage.png"},["content-length-range","0","15000000"]]}

Comment: it is working after I set $expectedMaxSize = 15000000; Thanks Ray and I will do more experiments with other options and you are awesome!