# fineuploader signature failing with google cloud upload

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, fine-uploader

I encounter a "Invalid policy document or request headers!" error, when trying to upload to a google cloud bucket.

My situation is this. I have a S3 fine-upload setup which works. I have the Amazon s3 client v. 5.15.6 downloaded web version downloaded from https://fineuploader.com/customize.html

I have the php server, provided by fineuploader, to sign the documents. This is CORS. It works when uploading to S3.

In order to make this work I've followed guide from here: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1158

The only things I have changed in my client is the

```
endpoint: 'BUCKET.storage.cloud.google.com',
accessKey: 'GOOG-ACCESSKEY'
```

In the php signing server I have only changed the environment variables

```
AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY="GOOGLEPRIVATEKEY"
AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY="GOOG-ACCESSKEY"
AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY="GOOGLEPRIVATEKEY"
S3_BUCKET_NAME="BUCKET"
```

As far as I can read this should work? At least the signing from my php server should work. It does with S3. My thought-process is this: Changing only variables stated above shouldn't give me "Invalid policy document or request headers!" as the request and response are the same as in the S3 example which works.

Hope someone has some insight into why signing suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271537/invalid-policy-document-or-request-headers) and [this](https://github.com/pankitgami/fineuploader-gcs-example) repository? This repository is more recent and complete example of how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem occurs when I try to upload to google cloud. I got it working with the same setup for aws. This is what confuses me. To my knowledge I should be able to use the same technique, but it doesn't work :(